# Word VBA: Macro to change cells in selection, and create a summary table of the tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bunch of tables in a document that look roughly like this:

```
| Thing     |   Title   |
|-----------|:---------:|
| Info      | A, B, C.  |
| Score     | Foo       |
| More Info | Long Text |
| Proof     | Blah      |

Figure 1
<Screenshot of Proof>
```

I'd like to make it look like this (Number in the upper left cell):

```
| Thing #1  |       Title       |
|-----------|:-----------------:|
| Info      | A, B, C.          |
| Score     | Foo               |
| More Info | Long Text         |
| Proof     | Blah <Screenshot> |
```

But, the there are many tables in the document, and I'd only like to use the ones "within selection".

In short: I have to take all tables within a selection and number them sequentially. 
I'd also like to make a table of these tables that looks like this:

```
| Number | Title | Score | Number of CSV's in Info |
|--------|:-----:|-------|-------------------------|
| 1      | Thing | Foo   | 3                       |
| ...    | ...   | ...   | ...                     |
| ...    | ...   | ...   | ...                     |
| ...    | ...   | ...   | ...                     |
```

Here is what I have so far:

Numbering Tables:

```
Sub NumberTablesSelection()
    Dim t As Integer

    Dim myRange as Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range

    With myRange
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            Set myCell = .Tables(t).Cell(1,1).Range
            myCell.Text = "Thing #" + t
            Next t
        End With
End Sub
```

Table of Tables (with info):

```
Sub TableOfThings()
    Dim t As Integer

    Dim myRange as Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range

    myTable = Tables.Add(Range:=tableLocation, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=4)
    myTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Number"
    myTable.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "Title"
    myTable.Cell(1,3).Range.Text = "Score"
    myTable.Cell(1,4).Range.Text = "Instances"

    With myRange
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count

            Set Title = .Tables(t).Cell(1,2).Range 
            Set Instances = .Tables(t).Cell(2,2).Range
            Set Score = .Tables(t).Cell(3,2).Range

            Set NewRow = myTable.Rows.Add
            NewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = t
            NewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = Title
            NewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = Score
            NewRow.Cells(4).Range.Text = Instances
        End With
End Sub
```

But they flat out don't work the way I want them to, and I can't seem to manage to get them to work.

Could someone provide me with a solution?

Comment: Please let me know if you need any extra information or details, I tried to give a minimum viable example, and then the code I have currently in its most simple form.

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Comment: In VBA, string plus number, such as `myCell.Text = "Thing #" + t`, will try to make the string into a number, and then do number plus number. Hence, `"Thing #" + t` will result in 'type mismatch' error. Do instead: `myCell.Text = "Thing #" & t`  (i.e. use ampersand).

Comment: I agree with rskar and also believe these lines may also be slightly off:  `Set myCell = .Tables(t).Cell(1,1).Range
            myCell.Text = "Thing #" + t`

Probably should be:  `Set myCell = .Tables(t).Cell(1,1)
            myCell.Range.Text = "Thing #" & t`

`myCell` should also be declared as a range

Comment: How can I get the table of tables to work on only those tables below my cursor, and insert the table at my cursor? (I've tried googling, not much to be found. I suspect I'm not using the right language in my question)

Comment: `dim tbl as Table: for each tbl in myRange.Tables: 'do stuff with the table: Next tbl`.  Or something like that?

Comment: Well, it seems there is enough info here to reward the bounty - but nobody has posted an answer - just comments. 

So, I guess the first person to put it all together into a working solution gets it. I'd do it - I have enough info to now - but, well, Credit where credit is due - right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to consider the following aspects for the macro to function as desired:

- A button or other object can’t be used to invoke the macro, as that’ll effectively change the selection. Instead, it can be run by either <kbd>Alt + F8</kbd> or a short cut key assigned to the macro
- The selection must be continuous. So, if there are 4 tables, selection of just table# 1, & 3 won’t work. It should rather be like table# 1 to 3.

With that and a few minor tweaks, the modified code as reproduced below should work.

```
Option Explicit
Sub NumberTablesSelection()
    Dim t As Integer, myRange, myCell As Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    With myRange
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            Set myCell = .Tables(t).Cell(1, 1).Range
            myCell.Text = "Thing #" & t
        Next t
    End With
End Sub
Sub TableOfThings()
    Dim t As Integer, myRange As Range, myTable As Table, NewRow As Row, Title As String, Instances As Integer, Score As String
    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=4)
    With myTable
        .Style = "Table Grid"
        .Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -603917569
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Number"
        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Title"
        .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "Score"
        .Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Instances"
    End With
    With myRange
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            Title = .Tables(t).Cell(1, 2).Range
            Instances = UBound(Split(.Tables(t).Cell(2, 2).Range, ",")) + 1
            Score = .Tables(t).Cell(3, 2).Range
            Set NewRow = myTable.Rows.Add
            With NewRow
                .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
                .Cells(1).Range.Text = t
                .Cells(2).Range.Text = txtClean(Title)
                .Cells(3).Range.Text = txtClean(Score)
                .Cells(4).Range.Text = Instances
            End With
        Next t
    End With
End Sub
Function txtClean(txt As String) As String
    txt = Replace(txt, Chr(7), "")
    txt = Replace(txt, Chr(13), "")
    txt = Replace(txt, Chr(11), "")
    txtClean = txt
End Function
```

Edit: the result for column `Instances` has been changed to "number of instances", rather than displaying the original values.

Comment: The only thing I haven't quiet figured out is how to have score be the number of values in the table, and not just the values themselves.

Comment: Can u give an example like what's the score in table 1, and table 2 is, and how it should be displayed in the summary?

Comment: the example is in the question, a simple CSV list. If the cell contains A, B, C, you can see in the question in the summary I have 3. As in, 3 values.

Comment: I also misspoke, I meant the info cell, and not the score. In the code I have it as instances

Comment: this can be attained by the Split function. i have updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based on the comments.  It's just based on reading your code without testing so hopefully this works.  If it needs some tweaks, please feel free to edit.

```
Sub NumberTablesSelection()
    Dim t As Integer

    Dim myRange as Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range

    With myRange
        For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
            Set myCell = .Tables(t).Cell(1,1)
            myCell.Range.Text = "Thing #" & t
            Next t
        End With
End Sub
```

Table of Tables (with info):

```
Sub TableOfThings()
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim tbl as Table
    Dim myRange as Range
    Set myRange = Selection.Range

    myTable = Tables.Add(Range:=tableLocation, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=4)
    myTable.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Number"
    myTable.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "Title"
    myTable.Cell(1,3).Range.Text = "Score"
    myTable.Cell(1,4).Range.Text = "Instances"

    t = 1
    For each tbl in myRange.Tables
        With tbl
            Set Title = .Cell(1,2).Range 
            Set Instances = .Cell(2,2).Range
            Set Score = .Cell(3,2).Range
        End With

       Set NewRow = myTable.Rows.Add
       With NewRow
           .Cells(1).Range.Text = t
           .Cells(2).Range.Text = Title
           .Cells(3).Range.Text = Score
           .Cells(4).Range.Text = Instances
      End With
      t = t + 1
    Next tbl

End Sub
```